# Best practice for obtaining embedded document metadata?

Tags: mongodb

So, my schema design requires that I use an embedded document format.  While I recognize that what I'm about to ask could be made easier by redesigning the schema, the current design meets all of the other requirements in place so I'm doing my best to make it work.

Consider the following rudementary schema:

```
{
    "_id" : "01234ABCD,
    "type" : "thing",
    "resources" : {
         foo : [
                 {
                   "herp" : "derp",
                 },

             ],
         bar : [
                 {
                   "herp" : "derp",
                 },
                 {
                   "derp" : "herp"
                 }
             ]
    },
}
```

Obviously the value that corresponds to the "resources" key is an embedded document.  I would like to be able to efficiently calculate the count of keys in that document, and derive results based upon tests on that value.  **It's important to note that the length and content of the embedded doc is an unknown quantity** - hence my reason for wanting to be able to query this meta.  Being a complete js idiot, I've managed to cobble together the following query.  For example, if I were to look for documents with more than 3 keys in the "resources" document:

```
  db.coll.find({$where: function(){ 
      var total = 0; 
      for(i in this['resources']){ 
          ++total; 
          if(total > 3){
              return true;
          }
      }    
  }})
```

As I'm pretty new to Mongo and terrible at js, I feel like there may be a smarter way to do this.  I'm also very curious to hear opinions on whether or not this goes against the Mongo ethos a bit by not pushing this processing to the client.  Any feedback or criticism of this approach and implementation are most welcome.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`aggregate` pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#aggregation-pipelines) to assemble metadata about the docs and then filter on them.

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        // Compute a total count of the keys in the resources docs
        keys: {$add: [{$size: '$resources.foo'}, {$size: '$resources.bar'}]},
        // Project the original doc
        doc: '$$ROOT'
    }},
    // Only include the docs that have more than 3 keys
    {$match: {keys: {$gt: 3}}}
])
```

Comment: Does this assume that the names of the keys in the embedded document are static?  Sorry, I should have been more clear - I've edited the original question to include the fact that the doc is of uncertain length or content.

Comment: @ajn Yes, it does. Using dynamic keys is usually a bad idea so you may want to rethink that; perhaps making `resources` an array instead.

Comment: Super naive comment - but is there a reason for this?  The keys are not auto-generated or ephemeral, but rather open-ended.  It makes sense for us to group the data based upon these keys, but obviously we may not fully understand the ramifications of that decision.

Comment: Dynamic keys make your docs difficult to query and group; what you're trying to do here is a good example.  You don't have a way to treat each resource in a general way.